# Flutter Web: image_picker plugin gets image from folder instead of webcam

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, imagepicker

While trying to open the webcam by selecting ImageSource.Camera in Flutter, the image picked is just getting an image from the folder and not from the webcam as expected.
Any workaround or alternative for solving the problem?

```
final pickedImage = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

This code is opening the file manager rather than webcam as I am expecting.

Comment: refer https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_for_web

Comment: funny no one comment on this, this is known issue. please check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85195